# MUI Datagrid, how to do conditional cellrender based on checkboxSelection

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, datagrid, frontend, mui-datatable

I am trying to make a conditional cellRender in a datagrid, if the row checkbox has been checked.

In my picture below, I want to remove the number counter component on that row when the checkbox is clicked.

Is there a way to do this with params? How else could I achieve this

```
const columns: GridColDef[] = [
    { field: 'id', headerName: 'LIO', flex: 1, minWidth: 80, maxWidth: 100 },
    { field: 'article', headerName: 'Artikel', flex: 1, minWidth: 100, maxWidth: 380 },
    { field: 'currentStock', headerName: 'Saldo', type: 'number', flex: 0.5, minWidth: 70 },
    {
      field: "inventedStock",
      headerName: "Inventerat Antal",
      flex: 0.5,
      minWidth: 130,
      type: 'number',

      renderCell: params => {
        if( params.row.checkboxSelection) {
          return (
            <ChooseNumber updateArticle={updateField} scannedArticle={{
              article: {
                compartments: undefined, units: [], price: 0, supplier: '', supplierArticleNr: '', name: '', alternativeNames: [], lioNr: '', alternativeProducts: [], Z41: false
              },
              unit: '', quantity: 2,
              nr: 3,
    
            }} ></ChooseNumber>
          );
        } else {
          return(2);
        }
  
        }
    },
```

[image: Datagrid]

I have tried to find a property in the datagrid params interface, but I can't figure it out. Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my knowledge it is not possible to do it only using the `params` since they don't contain any information about the status of the checkbox.

However the [selection of the DataGrid](https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/selection/#controlled-selection) component can be controlled. This can help us track the checked `ids` which we can use to conditionally render our columns.

To track the checked rows we need to add an new state like so

```js
const [selectedIds, setSelectedIds] = useState([]);
```

In the `renderCell` method we check if the `id` is in the `selectedIds` if so render the custom input, else render the other thing.

```js
{
  field: "inventedStock",
  headerName: "Inventerat Antal",
  flex: 0.5,
  minWidth: 130,
  type: "number",
  renderCell: (params) => {
    console.log(params);
    if (selectedIds.includes(params.id) === false) {
      return (
        <ChooseNumber
          updateArticle={updateField}
          scannedArticle={{
            article: {
              compartments: undefined, units: [], price: 0, supplier: "", supplierArticleNr: "", name: "", alternativeNames: [], lioNr: "", alternativeProducts: [], Z41: false,
            },
            unit: "",
            quantity: 2,
            nr: 3,
          }}
        ></ChooseNumber>
      );
    }
    return "2";
  },
}
```

The DataGrid component with your rows, columns and added selectionModel functionality

```js
<DataGrid
  rows={rows}
  columns={columns}
  ...
  selectionModel={selectedIds}
  onSelectionModelChange={(newModel) => {
    setSelectedIds(newModel);
  }}
/>
```

I hope this helps with your project!

Comment: Yay! Thank you so much! That worked like a charm. I also had to define the type in the state as such: useState<GridRowId[]>([])